# GraphQL Magento 2.4.4 How to add "Additional Options" add to cart

Tags: magento2, addtocart, graphql, additional-options

> We need to add additional data in cart items like code, label, value, etc. from graphql add to cart.
>
> We have reviewed the Magento docs block "CustomizableFieldOption" but not work with my situation.

[Magento Docs Url](https://magento2%20addtocart%20graphql%20additional-options)